# How to read the values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am tying to read the values in SQl.

I am creating one purchase order If suppose any body has updated the price for the inventory then I am first checking that price is available or not.

If that price is not available then I am First Inserting that price into the datbase & then map new price with the inventory.

I have already achieved this functionality but I have wrote five inline query for this now i need to
change the code & replace with the single stored procedure. & how I can write the logic into the SQL

Here is my code with the explanation

```
 //Checking that Buying Price Is Exist or not
            //string CheckingIBM = "select * from RS_Inventory_Buying_Master where buying_price                        ='" + UpdatedPrice + "'";
            //cm.TableConnect(CheckingIBM);

            //If Buying Price is Exist then Update PIIM table with new buying_product_id
            if (cmIS_Price_Exist.rs.Read())
            {

                //If Buying Price is Exist then Update PIIM table with new buying_product_id
                common cm1 = new common();
                string BuyingProductId = cmIS_Price_Exist.rs["buying_product_id"].ToString();

                string UpdatePIIM = "update RS_Purchase_Invoice_Info_Master set buying_product_id = '" + BuyingProductId + "', qty = '" + UpdatedQuantity + "',tax_id ='" + TaxDetails + "',picreated = 1  where purchase_order_no = '" + PO + "' and product_id = '" + ProductId + "'";
                cm1.TableInsert(UpdatePIIM);
                cm1.con.Close();
            }

             //If Buying Price does not Exist then first Insert the price & then Update the other tables
            else
            {
                //If Price is not exist then firsrt insert the price
                common cm2 = new common();
                string InsertBuyingPrice = "insert into RS_Inventory_Buying_Master (buying_price,latest) values ('" + UpdatedPrice + "','0')";
                cm2.TableInsert(InsertBuyingPrice);
                cm2.con.Close();

                //After inserting the price find the buying product Id of that price
                common cm3 = new common();
                string FindingUpdatedPrice = "select * from RS_Inventory_Buying_Master where buying_price ='" + UpdatedPrice + "'";
                cm3.TableConnect(FindingUpdatedPrice);

                //Now finallly after finding the buying price id by using the inserted Price. Now update the buying product id of PIIM
                if (cm3.rs.Read())
                {
                    string BuyingProductId = cm3.rs["buying_product_id"].ToString();

                    //Now finallly after finding the buying price id. Now update the buying product id of PIIM
                    common cm4 = new common();
                    string UpdatePIIM = "update RS_Purchase_Invoice_Info_Master set buying_product_id = '" + BuyingProductId + "', qty = '" + UpdatedQuantity + "',tax_id ='" + TaxDetails + "',picreated = 1 where purchase_order_no = '" + PO + "' and product_id = '" + ProductId + "'";
                    cm4.TableInsert(UpdatePIIM);
                    cm4.con.Close();
                }
                cm3.con.Close();

            }
```

Any suggesion will be appreciated.

Comment: You should start by working out what parameters your stored procedure should accept, then find out the syntax of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` command in SQL and start with that.

Comment: I know how to create stored procedure my stored procedure will accept all the parameters that are in the query but problem is how to check that price is not present in the database & if not exist then insert new price into the database

Comment: does your question pertain to reading values in SQL? what are you having trouble with: creating the procedure? the basic logic of your system?

Comment: I suggest you post the stored procedure you have so far, otherwise it appears you have made no effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @BuyingProductId varchar(50)
set @BuyingProductId = (select isnull(buying_product_id, '') from RS_Inventory_Buying_Master where buying_price = @UpdatedPrice)

if(@BuyingProductId <> '')
begin
   --your update query
   update RS_Purchase_Invoice_Info_Master set buying_product_id = @BuyingProductId , 
   qty = @UpdatedQuantity ,tax_id = @TaxDetails ,picreated = 1 
   where purchase_order_no = @PO 
   and product_id = @ProductId ;
end
else
begin
    --your insert query
   insert into RS_Inventory_Buying_Master (buying_price,latest) 
   values (@UpdatedPrice,'0')
    set @BuyingProductId = (SELECT @@IDENTITY)  
   update RS_Purchase_Invoice_Info_Master set buying_product_id = @BuyingProductId , 
   qty = @UpdatedQuantity ,tax_id = @TaxDetails ,picreated = 1 
   where purchase_order_no = @PO 
   and product_id = @ProductId ;    
end
```

Check with this query. Please make sure to create new sp and provide all the value like @UpdatedQuantity etc.